# return json_encode response from wordpress php file

Tags: php, json

I have a wordpress file I"ve made in order to authenticate a user via an app.

Everything works except my return statement here is blank, but I want to return a json version of this data:

```
if( isset( $_POST)){

/* Get user data */
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $_POST['email'] );
//echo 'User is ' . $user->first_name ;

if ( $user ){
    $password_check = wp_check_password( $_POST['password'], $user->user_pass, $user->ID );

    if ( $password_check ){
        /* Generate a unique auth token */
        $token = wp_rand(30);
        //echo($token);


            /* Return generated token and user ID*/
            $response['status'] = true;
            $response['data'] = array(
                'auth_token'    =>  $token,
                'user_id'       =>  $user->ID,
                'user_login'    =>  $user->user_login
            );
            $response['msg'] = 'Successfully Authenticated';

            return json_encode($response);

    }
}
}
```

I can echo up to the `$token` variable, but I need to return the whole response object.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Either return the object with `return $response` or echo out the json `echo json_encode($response)`

Comment: For some reason the return doesn't work, but echo did! Thank you. if you want to make an answer for that I'll accept asap